# S3 Encryption not working from spark-submit command

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have configured an encryption enabled EMR cluster. When I try to insert data from hive or spark-shell , Then the data is getting encrypted in S3. 
But when I do it from spark-submit client or YARN mode, the data is not encrypted.

I have configured EMR cluster with the below settings:

```
"fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption": "true", 
"fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId":"axxxxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyy-123a45678901"
```

A simple `saveAsTextFile(s3://)` from spark-shell, I am able to see the encrypted data, but when I spark-submit an application my data is not encrypting.

Any idea why this issue?

Comment: need more details of your code, configurations, all versions etc...

Comment: I have configured EMR cluster with the below settings: "fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption": "true",  
"fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId":"a4567b8-9900-12ab-1234-123a45678901"  . When I am doing a simple insert from hive to S3 , I am able to see its aws kms encrypted,
Also when a simple saveAsTextFile(s3://) from spark-shell, I am able to see the encrypted data, but when I spark-submit an application my data is not encrypting.

Comment: add it to question, question look blank with limited information.